# Exec's unless command prevents my catalog to compile

Tags: exec, puppet

I am facing some strange issues with Puppet 2.6.7. I have an exec that is using a shell script as command. Also, I want to use the same script to do the 'unless' property of exec, just passing a flag to test some things:

```
exec { "myexec":
  path        => '/bin:/usr/bin',
  command     => "/opt/myapp/script.sh -o ${name}",
  unless      => "/opt/myapp/script.sh -o ${name} -t",
}
```

I am using puppet with the puppetmaster. If I leave the code as shown above, I get an error: "Could not evaluate: Could not find command '/opt/myapp/script.sh'" and the process throws an error when compiling. However, if I remove the unless line everything compiles properly. The weird thing is that for both the command is the same, but just the unless complaints about not finding it.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this or any workaround? Is it a bug in Puppet 2.6.14?

Thanks for the help!

Hector.

Answer (score 0):

`unless` runs before `command`, that's why you don't get an error for `command`. The problem is with `path`, here is the correct declaration:

```
path => [ '/bin/', '/usr/bin/' ]
```

Comment: Thank for your anwser. I have tried and the problem is still there. I know that `unless` runs before `command`. I meant that if I have both in the exec it does not compile, but if I just have `command`, it works fine.

Comment: Ok, then try: path => [ '/opt/myapp/', '/bin/', '/usr/bin/' ], command => "script.sh -o ${name}", unless => "script.sh -o ${name} -t",